# How to check if the file is uploaded to form in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I created a form with Django. What I want is A warning popup appears when a user does not upload file to the form.
How can I do it?

**my code:**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form|crispy }}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="is-file"  onclick="return confirm_submit()" id="isEmpty">Make Non-report Analysis</button>
</form>
...

<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_submit() {
    var x = document.getElementById("isEmpty").value;
    window.alert(x)
    if (!x){
        return confirm('are you sure?');
        }
}
</script>
```

**forms.py**

```
class PdfForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pdf
        fields = ['title', 'pdf', 'document_type', 'year', 'payment_behavior']
        labels = {
            "payment_behavior": "Please Select the Payment Behavior of the Customer:  ",
            "document_type": "Document Type",
            "title": "Document Name",
            "pdf": "Please Select a File to Upload",
            "year": "Financial Table Year"
        }
```

**models.py**

```
class Pdf(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=customer_directory_path, null=True, blank=True)
    document_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Select', choices=CHOICES)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if user press `cancel` or not button using `!confirm(..)` then cancel your form submission else submit your form.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function confirm_submit() {
  var flag = true;
  var x = document.getElementById("isEmpty").value;
  if (!x) {
    //if press cancel..
    if (!confirm("Are your about this .. ??")) {
      flag = false;
    }
  }
  return flag; //return true/false
}
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="isEmpty">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="is-file" onclick="return confirm_submit()" id="isEmpty">Make Non-report Analysis</button>
</form>
```